# Logging functionality not working ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

My log4net stopped working and just won't start again!

My web.config file:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
             type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
<log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender"
          type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
        <encoding value="utf-8" />
        <lockingModel value="MinimalLock" />
        <file value="App_Data\Logs\Test-log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] – %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="All" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

The class that uses it:

```
using log4net;

public class Connection
{
  private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Connection));
```

My Global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "log4net.config"));

}
```

Why is the below executing but not logging/creating a logfile even? The output window isn't throwing any errors.

```
 log.Debug("Entering Function: Insert_PatientTable");
```

Comment: Quick aside, consider using `System.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "log4net.config")` this can help with and without trailing /

Comment: Are you also sure that the `App_Data\Logs` folder exists AND your application domain identity has write access (under normal circumstances of deploy you would automagically add that).

Comment: does the application pool have rights to write to App_Data\Logs\?

Comment: @Aron Where do I use that piece of code? App_Data exists. I thought the Appender does the creation of files for us? The logs folder inside it doesn't.

Comment: @EricHerlitz How do I check if the permissions are in place?

Comment: Right click on the folder and check properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing your code from `Application_Start` into `Session_Start`. `Application_Start` is only run the first time your site is called after the corresponding `ApplicationPool` started. `Session_Start` is called for every user.

Comment: `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "log4net.config"));` Is now present both in Application Start and Session Start. I still do not have a logfile.